# How to break down/dissect Rails 5 load times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

Is there a way I can get a detailed breakdown of load times in Rails 5? I've got one page that is taking 500+ms just on views and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I just want that time broken down so I can see what's causing it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What about right click on page, then "Inspect element" and then check "Network monitor". You should be able to see each element load time in miliseconds - [check out more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)

Answer (score -1):

Rack-mini-profiler is what I was looking for.

https://www.speedshop.co/2015/08/05/rack-mini-profiler-the-secret-weapon.html